# How to link TypeSense with my MongoDB database?

Tags: regex, mongodb, elasticsearch, solr, full-text-search

I have a MongoDB Database that contains a collection of about 3 billion documents and that is willing to grow in the future.

I've set up a full text search index within that database. It is fast, but I'm not really satisfied by the results of query searches and I would like a faster search engine for regex searches.

I heard linking Solr / ElasticSeach to Mongo would be a great idea to make faster queries.. What about TypeSense ?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late response, but I do have some advice.

First of all, I'm making the assumption that your Mongo database is user generated content.

Yes, Typesense would absolutely work for 3 billion documents as is it nearly infinitely scalable, but it depends on the amount of ram you have, and don't forget that **you cannot search for an exact keyword with Typesense**. If that's something that you need, you can eliminate Typesense.

Elasticsearch is the best solution for you though. It's not easy to setup, but there are many guides on how to do so. 3 billion records is massive, but Elasticsearch is built for those datasets exclusively.

If you're not willing to setup Elasticsearch, then keep your current setup as a couple hundred milliseconds shouldn't be an issue. Elasticseach can be very costly for large datasets as well but has the absolute most complete features.

Typesense has made a comparison of the 4 most common search engines and their features here: https://typesense.org/typesense-vs-algolia-vs-elasticsearch-vs-meilisearch/